# Sliding Menu without moving header

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am creating a sliding menu drawer in my application...the problem is when i am sliding the menu it is sliding the heading too wheres i just want the content to move with the slider. how can i prevent header from moving. i am using fragments for my code:

MainActivity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        btnMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        homeScreenFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeScreenFragment).commit();

        // configure the SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu=new SlidingMenu(this);

        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new HomeNavFragment()).commit();

        findViewById(R.id.imgBtnMenu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menu.toggle(true);
            }
        });
```

HomeScreenFragment:

```
public final String[] podName = new String[] { "NO Text", "NO Text",
            "NO Text", "NO Text" };

    public final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.pod_img1, R.drawable.pod_img2,
            R.drawable.pod_img3, R.drawable.pod_img1 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_homescreen, container,
                false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        addItemsToListView();

    }

    private void addItemsToListView() {
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < podName.length; i++) {

            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], podName[i]);
            // RowItem item = new RowItem(imageUrl[i], deityName[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        setAdapter();
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
        podListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    Navigation Fragment: 

public static final String[] nav_title = new String[] { "CLE & Events",
                "Pictorial Roster", "Publications", "On-Demand CLE", "Court Info",
                "LBA Alerts", "My Profile", "Notification Settings",
                "App Support & Feedback", "Share this App", "Developer", " ", " " };

        public static final int[] nav_icon = { R.drawable.ic_menu_calender,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_roster, R.drawable.ic_menu_publication,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_filebox, R.drawable.ic_menu_court,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_bubble, R.drawable.ic_menu_profile,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_reminder, R.drawable.ic_menu_share,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_developer, R.drawable.ic_menu_developer,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_developer };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_homescreen, container,
                false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setAdapter();

        /*addItemsToListView();*/

    }



    private void setAdapter() {
        NavigationMenuAdapter adapter = new NavigationMenuAdapter(getActivity(),nav_title,nav_icon);
        podListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Xml:

layout_home:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/include_header" />

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_home">
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

layout_homescreen

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/podListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

menu.xml
```

Comment: By header, you mean you don't want your ActionBar Title to move?

Comment: @nDroidDev: no i have placed a header in my main activity, i dont want it to move

Comment: nDroidDev: yes i dont want to actionbar to move

Comment: Then i think you should you v4's Navigation Drawer.. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: nDroidDev: this will not move my content...i want to content to move right with the drawer

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to move your content area with sidepanel + ActionBar should remain static, best way would be to implement v4 widget **SlidingPaneLayou**t (android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout).

[here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html) is a good example that explains how to implement SlidingPaneLayout

And please go through [Developer's site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) for proper understanding.

Hope it helps..!! :)